# How to call cgi script from ruby

Tags: ruby, cgi

I've a remote cgi script hosted on Apache using SSL. It takes in two input variables `a` and `b`.

I want to call call the cgi script with right input variables using ruby.

Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind providing some details about how you access the CGI in question?  And what do you mean by call?

Comment: I wish to invoke the cgi. I tried doing it via. Net::HTTP.get(...), but it did not work. I got a Connection Reset By Peer error

Comment: Net::HTTP is definitely the package to use. Connection Reset by Peer seems to indicate that the server refuses the connection for some reason, perhaps some authentication related reason. Can you access the Apache logs to figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you want to make a remote call to the CGI script via HTTP then take a look at using [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) plus [CGI.escape](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI.html#M000065) to encode the values of `a` and `b`. There are some examples of doing this using GET and POST in the Net::HTTP documentation.